# No route matches "devise/sessions"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I install Devise in my application everything was working fine, but suddenly it starts to give me this error **No route matches {:controller=>"devise/sessions"}**

My routes

```
resources :profiles

get "payment_notifications/create"
get "cart_items/destroy"

devise_for :users

namespace :admin do
  resources :pages
  resources :users
  resources :books
  resources :messages
  resources :programs
  resources :catalogs
  resources :courses
  resources :online_courses
  resources :orders
  resources :announcements
  resources :guides
  resources :onliners
  resources :articles
  get '', to: 'dashboards#index', as: '/'
  match '/guides_calendar', :controller => 'guides', :action => 'calendar'
end

resources :articles
resources :payment_notifications
resources :tests
resources :carts
resources :online_courses, :path => 'cursos_en_linea' do
  member do
    get 'add_to_cart'
  end
end

resources :cart_items
resources :pages
resources :books, :path => 'libros' do
 member do
   get 'add_to_cart'
 end
end

resources :messages
resources :programs, :path => 'videos' do
 member do
   get 'add_to_cart'
 end
end

resources :catalogs
match '/empresas', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'empresas'
match '/quienessomos', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'quienes_somos'
match '/privacidad', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'privacidad'
match '/comunidad', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'comunidad'
resources :courses, :path => 'cursos' do
 member do
   get 'add_to_cart'
 end
end

root :to => 'messages#index'
```

application.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
   <li class="login"><%= link_to('<i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Carrito'.html_safe, current_user.carts.last) %></li>
   <li class="login"><%= link_to('<i class="icon-user"></i> Your Account'.html_safe, current_user.profile) %></li>
   <li class="login"><%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %></li>
<% else %>
   <li class="login"><%= link_to("<i class='icon-user'></i> Login ".html_safe, new_user_session_path) %></li>
<% end %>
```

I also run rails g devise:install and rails g devise User
I have the devise:views but I didn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I think it is an odd error.

In my application.html.erb I had:

```
    <li><%= link_to "Servicios", :action => "index" %></li>
```

And changed to:

```
    <li><%= link_to "Servicios" %></li>
```

This line of code that I think it has nothing to do with the devise controller, was the error.